# Como gerar ID sequencial?

Tags: java

Estou tentando gerar um ID sequencial para cada usuário cadastrado no sistema, mas todos os usuários saem com o mesmo número do ID gerado.

```
public class User {  
    // ...  
    int id=1;  
    public void gerarid() {  
        id++;  
    }  
    // ...
}

public class Mein {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        User u1 = new User();  
        // ...  
        u1.gerarid();  
        // ...  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Você precisa capturar o número de ID gerado, ou o numero mais alto e somar `1` a partir dele. O que acontece no seu código é que cada vez que o script é executado você coloca o id como `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cada usuário que você cria, você está dizendo que o `id` dele um é 1. Isso porque o comando `int id = 1` está dentro da classe `User`, e o método `gerarid()`, que também está dentro da classe, só irá incrementar o `id` do `User` o qual o esse método `gerarid()` pertence, por exemplo:

```java
User u1 = new User(); // u1 possui um atributo chamado id (u1.id) com o valor 1 
User u2 = new User(); // u2 possui um atributo chamado id (u2.id) com o valor 1
u1.gerarid();
```

Ao chamar `u1.gerarid()`, a instrução `id++` está incrementando o `id` do `User` `u1`, sem nenhuma relação com `u2`, muito menos com o seu `id` (`u2.id`). O resultado do código acima seria:

```java
u1.id: 2 // O id de u1 foi incrementado ao chamar u1.gerarid()
u2.id: 1 // Não foi alterado
```

Para resolver o seu problema, você precisa de uma variável que não pertença a um `User`, essa variável irá guardar o `id` que o próximo `User` a ser criado deve ter:

```java
public class User {  
    // ...  
    int id; // Receberá o valor de contadorDeId
    // ...
}

public class Mein {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int contadorDeId = 1;
        User u1 = new User();
        u1.id = contadorDeId++; // Atribui e depois incrementa contadorDeId para 2

        // ...  

        User u2 = new User();
        u2.id = contadorDeId++; // Atribui e depois incrementa contadorDeId para 3...
    }  
}
```

Com isso, você não precisa do método `gerarId()`, pelo menos não dentro da classe `User`. Você pode usar o conceito de [construtores](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_constructors.asp) para atribuir o `id` a cada novo `User` de uma maneira mais elegante.

Comment: Valeuu, seu método é muito mais simples e eu dificultado kkk

Answer (score 1):

É só transformar o campo `id` em `static`. A palavra chave `static` indica ao compilador que que ao invés de criar um campo em uma instancia você quer criar um campo em uma classe.

```
class User {  

        // Unica mudança significativa no código.
        static int id;  

        public void gerarid() {  
            id++;  
        }  

}

public class Main {    


    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        User u1 = new User();  

        // Gera 10 Ids e os imprime
        for (int i = 0;i < 10 ;i++ ) {
           u1.gerarid();  
           System.out.println(u1.id);
        }

    }  
}
```